# "Weaker continuum hypothesis:" $2^{\aleph_0} < 2^{\aleph_1}$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

For finite cardinals $A < B$, it's clear that the powerset $2^A$ is smaller than the powerset $2^B$.

However, it seems that when $A < B$ are infinite cardinals, the strict inequality cannot be proven from ZFC: [Easton's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem) tells us that in general, unless something is known about the cofinalities $\text{cf}(A), \text{cf}(B)$, the most we can say is that $2^A \leq 2^B$. (That is, there are models for which both $2^A = 2^B$ and $2^A < 2^B$.)

My question is about the smallest possible case: $A = \aleph_0$, $B = \aleph_1$. If we had that $\aleph_1 = 2^{\aleph_0}$ (Continuum Hypothesis) then obviously we would have $2^{\aleph_0} < 2^{(2^{\aleph_0})} = 2^{\aleph_1}$, but it seems like that's probably a lot stronger than we would need to show $2^{\aleph_0} < 2^{\aleph_1}$. Contrapositively, if $2^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_1}$, that would imply the negation of the Continuum Hypothesis, but again, this seems like a very strong sufficient condition for $\neg CH$ that wouldn't be *necessary.*

Can we show for sure that $2^{\aleph_0} < 2^{\aleph_1}$ or $2^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_1}$? Is there simply no canonical way to answer this (any more than for the Continuum Hypothesis)? What is the status of this question, and are there any well-known open statements to which it is equivalent? I played around with it in a desultory way to discover why approaches like diagonalization or Konig's theorem wouldn't work to establish an injection $2^{\aleph_1} \to 2^{\aleph_0}$ or lack of same, but maybe there are some cleverer techniques out there I'm not familiar with.

Comment: I think this post may have been closed in error, as the “duplicate question” is substantially different from mine. The alleged “duplicate” places a strong restriction on the particular value of $2^{\aleph_0}$ which mine does not, only asks about the value of $2^{\aleph_1}$ in that narrow context, and doesn’t ask for other statements besides CH which would relate to this powerset inequality.

Comment: Asking "Is X finite" is a weaker question of "Is X empty".

Comment: @AsafKaragila Right, and if my question had been "Is X finite", knowing the answer to "Is X empty" wouldn't fully answer my question. Analogously, knowing the answer to "What is the relationship of $2^{\aleph_1}$ to $2^{\aleph_0}$ when $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_2$" doesn't answer my question, which is, "$2^{\aleph_1} > 2^{\aleph_0}$ seems to be a weaker version of CH, has this particular relationship been studied in its own right (rather than as a general case of Easton or w/e), are there interesting related results out there?"

Comment: @AsafKaragila I specifically read the question you linked as "duplicate" before asking this, and asked it anyway, because the "duplicate" question didn't actually answer what I wanted to know. Too narrow.

Comment: How should anyone know that you read that question? Look at the answer you received. I am not the only one who read your question *that way*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sure, maybe at a cursory glance it looks similar (and a cursory glance is clearly what it got, since this question was open for, like, five minutes). All I'm saying is, if the linked "duplicate" answered my actual question, I wouldn't be complaining about not actually getting my question answered.

Comment: And all I'm saying is that you should edit your question to clarify this better.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I’m not sure where the lack of clarity was in the original question? We’ve just had a public conversation about the multiple unsubtle reasons this question is different than the other one.

Comment: Look, fact is that you're telling me how the duplicate does not answer your question. The one answer you received so far is in line of the duplication. You keep insisting to me that it's not an answer. Why aren't you interacting with Noah as well? (Frankly, upon a closer reading of your question, I'm confused by your statement. You're aware of Easton's theorem and its consequences, but not enough to apply them to $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$?)

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$. And Easton's theorem already tells us this: for example, the function sending $\kappa$ to $\kappa^+$ for $\kappa>\aleph_0$ and sending $\aleph_0$ to $\aleph_2$ satisfies the requirements in Easton's theorem.

(Of course Easton is overkill here: just start with a model of $\mathsf{CH}$ and add $\aleph_2$-many Cohen reals. This is what Cohen did in his original model of $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg CH}$ if memory serves.)

Amusingly, $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$ can happen for non-silly reasons: the **proper forcing axiom** $\mathsf{PFA}$ proves that $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$, for example.)

Comment: @Asaf I would have liked to let a few other people have a bite at the apple, since it's a somewhat open-ended question with a variety of possible answers, although what Noah has to say about PFA is certainly relevant.

Comment: Noah and @Asaf: To explain why Easton's theorem doesn't satisfy me, let me analogize it to Skolem's theorem. If you asked, "Can we prove that the reals are uncountable?" and someone told you, "Well, according to Skolem, the reals could have any infinite cardinality including $\aleph_0$." Technically that's *true* (depending on the choice of model). But we don't--at any rate, **I** don't--then bite the bullet and say "There's no way of answering the question of $\Bbb{R}$'s cardinality other than to say it's infinite."

Comment: @RiversMcForge I don't understand your analogy here. The Lowenheim-Skolem theorem **doesn't** say that at all; it says that any *"concrete" description of* the reals will also hold of countable structures. I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: *That's* how I feel about $2^{\aleph_0}$ and $2^{\aleph_1}$. Just because there are consistent models where those two cardinals are equal or unequal, doesn't mean there could literally be any possible answer to that question and they're all equally valid. There is some relationship of $2^{\aleph_0}$ and $2^{\aleph_1}$ that is more useful, better describes the infinite sets that we actually work with, just like $\Bbb{R}$ having cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ is a more useful and meaningful answer than $\Bbb{R}$ having cardinality $\aleph_0$.

Comment: "Let N denote the natural numbers and R the reals. It follows from the theorem that the theory of (N, +, ×, 0, 1) (the theory of true first-order arithmetic) has uncountable models, and that the theory of (R, +, ×, 0, 1) (the theory of real closed fields) has a countable model.... Another consequence that was considered particularly troubling is **the existence of a countable model of set theory,** which nevertheless must satisfy the sentence saying the real numbers are uncountable."

Comment: Lowenheim-Skolem, again, **doesn't** say that "$\mathbb{R}$ can have cardinality $\aleph_0$." It's more subtle than that. If you want to phrase it in terms of models of set theory, it says that there is a model $M$ such that the thing $M$ thinks is $\mathbb{R}$ **externally** cardinality $\aleph_0$, despite what $M$ thinks. But note the crucial mixing of internal and external issues there. By contrast, Cohen says that there is a model $M$ such that **internally** the things $M$ thinks are $2^{\aleph_0}$ and $2^{\aleph_1}$ are in bijection with each other. This is extremely different.

Comment: Downwards Lowenheim-Skolem is not a limitation on **what sentences we can prove** in a given *theory*, but rather **what structures we can pin down** in a given *logic*. It's a totally different beast from Cohen's argument (Easton is overkill, per the above).

Comment: It's an analogy, not an equivalence. I think you're overthinking the point of comparison a little bit. Maybe there's more leeway and it's less clear what the comparison should be between $2^{\aleph_0}$ and $2^{\aleph_1}$, but there's definitely some answer to that question that has more validity than other answers, we just hasn't found it yet.

Comment: @RiversMcForge "there's definitely some answer to that question that has more validity than other answers, we just hasn't found it yet." And you think that why, exactly? Regardless, it sounds like your actual question is: "Are there 'reasonably natural' principles settling the question of whether $2^{\aleph_0}<2^{\aleph_1}$?" This is quite different from the way you've phrased the question, in my opinion. (Aside: the nuance I'm highlighting around dLS versus other results is really quite important - interpreting dLS as saying "the reals could be countable" is only going to cause issues later.)

Comment: "And you think that why, exactly?" See, that illustrates my point. If you want to scoff at the idea that some consistent models might be more valid or accurate or useful than others, you have to grant that a countable model of set theory implying $\Bbb{R}$ is countable *in any way, internal or external,* is just as valid as the typical one we use, and probably way easier to work with. Why don't we use a countable model, then? Because it would lack the second-order properties we demand of $\Bbb{R}$. Why would it be any different for the question of whether $2^{\aleph_0} < 2^{\aleph_1}$?

Comment: @RiversMcForge That's a slippery slope argument which I don't buy at all, and I think it's predicated on ignoring important distinctions. But this comment thread is getting long; if you want to keep talking let's move to chat, and regardless you should consider clarifying your question per my previous comment.

Comment: My position on questions like CH, or the weaker $2^{\aleph_0} < 2^{\aleph_1}$, falls somewhere between multiverse, Platonic, and formalist: https://mathoverflow.net/a/25199 That is, there are consistent models of set theory which give CH or not CH, which have validity in different contexts (like geometry w/ and w/o Parallel Postulate), but only one of those multiverses captures $\Bbb{N}$ and $\Bbb{R}$ as we have traditionally understood them. Your clarification suggestion is a good one. My "actual" question was more appropriate for MO (since it's a rather technical one) and I'll ask it there.